# In PowerBi how can you writeformula that can filter multiple columns in just one DAX formula?

Tags: filter, powerbi

Basically, I am trying to calculate the percent of a minority group within the larger population. I have few things I have to take into account - I have 3 types of information to get this answer each in a different column. First column (ethnicity) I need to extract only those that identify as "Hispanic", second column (level) only those that are "Officer", third column (event) I need to extract if they are a "current" employee. I need the count of this number to later utilize it to get the percentage against larger population. Any ideas how I can go about this?

Comment: Edit your question, add some dummy data and your desired output from calculation;

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.